expand parameter pack with boolean operation
I tried to do function that checks if the argument matches specific values.
I think know how to do it with recursion or std::initializer_list, but I want to do it with fold. Here is non working code:
template<typename T, T ...ts>
constexpr bool is_in(T value){
    return (ts == value) || ... || (false);
}

int main(){
    if constexpr(is_in<int, 1, 2, 3>(1))
        return 10;

}

Also I would like to get rid of specifying the type if possible (e.g. the <int>)
Want solution in C++17, but C++20 would be interesting to see as well.

Always post complete error along with your question.

the code is totally incorrect. I just show what I want to do. no need of errors.

Just put another bracket and it will start working as in return ((ts == value) || ... || (false)).

See demo

Thanks works. any idea how I get rid of T ?

The additional template parameter type can be avoided by template<auto ... Ts> constexpr bool is_in(std::common_type_t<decltype(Ts)...> value){...}

Fold expressions must be enclosed in (...): return ((ts == value) || ... || (false));.
Also you can drop || false, it's implicit for || folds.

Also I would like to get rid of specifying the type if possible (e.g. the <int>)

You can do this by replacing <typename T, T ...ts> with e.g. <auto ...ts, typename T>.
But if I was you, I'd pass all alternatives as function parameters (to allow them to be changed at runtime).

passing parameters on command line also make function looks clear. will post answer

You just need to surround the whole expression with parenthesis as shown below:
template<typename T, T ...ts>
constexpr bool is_in(T value){
//---------v-------------------------------v--->added parnthesis 
    return ((ts == value) || ... || (false));
}

Working demo


any idea how I get rid of T

Yes, You can also use the placeholder type auto to make it work without explicilty specifying int by replacing <typename T, T ...ts> with <auto ...ts, typename T>

As per suggestion of @HolyBlackCat, here is the version with parameters of the function itself.
Looks much clear and get rid of specifying the <T>.
template<typename T, T ...ts>
constexpr bool is_in1(T value){
    static_assert(sizeof...(ts) > 0);
    return ((ts == value) || ...);
}

template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
constexpr bool is_in2(T value, Ts... ts){
    static_assert(sizeof...(ts) > 0);
    return ((ts == value) || ...);
}

int main(){
    if constexpr(is_in1<int, 3,4,5,1>(1)){
    //    return 20;
    }

    if constexpr(is_in2(1, 3,4,5,1))
        return 10;

}

